# Apache redirecting without provocation; dropping port?

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

This is a new issue to me and has been driving me nuts for the past hour or two. I have an Apache server running on port 8000 (confirmed in `ports.conf` and by `nmap`) yet any request to it is automatically redirected to port 80 (specifically, the port is dropped so 80 is default); the request is then refused.

Things I have tried:

- Checked Apache configurations
- Disabled `mod_rewrite`
- Checked iptables (and disabled to be sure)

Here's me running `wget` against it just so you can see what exactly is happening

```
--2010-07-01 04:02:14--  http://10.37.15.166:8000/
Connecting to 10.37.15.166:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://10.37.15.166/ [following]
--2010-07-01 04:02:15--  http://10.37.15.166/
Connecting to 10.37.15.166:80... failed: Connection refused.
zsh: exit 4     wget http://10.37.15.166:8000/
```

Anybody have suggestions? At this point I can't even figure out *what* is causing the redirect, much less the port drop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem to be an issue with your httpd.conf file (there is clearly a redirection (301))
Have you checked whether there are other default httpd-module files included by default?
Example: conf.d/php.conf --- conf.d/welcome.conf

Comment: Turns out this was caused by an idiotic piece of software redirecting traffic based off a setting. It didn't have anything do with Apache,  but you're technically correct so √!

Answer (score 0):

Out of my head and without actually knowing what your configuration looks like, put this to your httpd.conf and restart apache:

```
UseCanonicalName off
```

Comment: Yeah, tried that too; wasn't it. (see above comment)